# Converting decimal number to binary Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, binary, decimal, converters

Hi I have made an IOS app that converts binary, hexadecimal and decimal values. It all works fine except for my decimal to binary conversion. Here is what I have. It returns 0s and 1s but far too many. Can anyone tell me why this is or help me with a better method?

```
NSString *newDec = [display text]; //takes user input from display
NSString *string = @"";
NSUInteger x = newDec;
int i = 0;
while (x > 0) {
    string = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", x&1] stringByAppendingString:string];
    x = x>> 1;
    ++i;
}
display.text = string; //Displays result in ios text box
```

Comment: I tested you code, and it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSUInteger x = [newDec integerValue];
```

And next time don't ignore the Compiler's "Incompatible pointer to Integer conversion" hint...

Explanation: Afaik, assigning an object to an int, actually assigns the address of the object to that integer, not the content of the string (which is what you want).